# Verifying Syntax of a Massive SQL Update Command

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I'm new to SQL Server and am doing some cleanup of our transaction database. However, to accomplish the last step, I need to update a column in one table of one database with the value from another column in another table from another database.

I found a SQL update code snippet and re-wrote it for our own needs but would love someone to give it a once over before I hit the execute button since the update will literally affect hundreds of thousands of entries.

So here are the two databases:

Database 1: `Movement`

- Table 1: `ItemMovement`
- Column 1: `LongDescription` (datatype: text / up to 40 char)

Database 2: `Item`

- Table 2: `ItemRecord`
- Column 2: `Description` (datatype: text / up to 20 char)

Goal: set `Column1` from db1 to the value of `Colum2` from db2.

Here is the code snippet:

```
update table1
set table1.longdescription = table2.description
from movement..itemmovement as table1
inner join item..itemrecord as table2 on table1.itemcode = table2.itemcode
where table1.longdescription <> table2.description
```

I added the last "where" line to prevent SQL from updating the column where it already matches the source table.

This should execute faster and just update the columns that have garbage. But as it stands, does this look like it will run? And lastly, is it a straightforward process, using SQL Server 2005 Express to just backup the entire `Movement` db before I execute? And if it messes up, just restore it?

Alternatively, is it even necessary to re-cast the tables as table1 and table 2? Is it valid to execute a SQL query like this:

```
update movement..itemmovement
set itemmovement.longdescription = itemrecord.description
from movement..itemmovement
inner join item..itemrecord on itemmovement.itemcode = itemrecord.itemcode
where itemmovement.longdescription <> itemrecord.description
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The query looks pretty decent. Why don't you just create a new column called `movement.itemmovement.longdescription_test` and update that with this query? Once updated, you can spot check whether information in that field is correct or not. If it is correct, just run `update movement.itemmovement set longdescription = longdescription_test` and then drop `longdescription_test` column?

Comment: I'm "home schooled by Google" on SQL and have only been learning about select statements and updates from within a single table. I didn't know you could create a column in this way. Can you elaborate on syntax or would it all be just the same if I created it using SQL Express's GUI? Btw, I updated my OP with a more direct update query. Thoughts?

Comment: Who gave you this task? Do they know you are asking such things here?

Comment: I gave myself this task. I'm both owner operator of a small market in the Bay Area that uses NCR's ACS software. The thing is a monolith though, with over a decade of add-ons and patches. On top of the mess is a really out-dated SQL Express 2005 backend, which houses our 10,000 some PLU's and electronic journal. The bulk of the PLU data is garbage left from when they did a data dump from other markets to get us up and running. I was better off building the PLU database from scratch.  5 years later and with a better understanding of the system, I'm taking steps to cleanup the SQL databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to alias your tables but I recommend you do for faster typing and reduce the chances of making a typo.

```
update m
set m.longdescription = i.description
from movement..itemmovement as m
inner join item..itemrecord as i on m.itemcode = i.itemcode
where m.longdescription <> i.description
```

In the above query I have shortened the alias using `m` for itemmovement and `i` for itemrecord.

When a large number of records are to be updated and there's question whether it would succeed or not, always make a copy in a test database (residing on a test server) and try it out over there. In this case, one of the safest bet would be to create a new field first and call it `longdescription_text`. You can make it with SQL Server Management Studio Express (SSMS) or using the command below:

```
use movement;
alter table itemmovement add column longdescription_test varchar(100);
```

The syntax here says `alter table itemmovement` and `add a new column called longdescription_test` with datatype of `varchar(100)`. If you create a new column using SSMS, in the background, SSMS will run the same alter table statement to create a new column.

You can then execute

```
update m
set m.longdescription_test = i.description
from movement..itemmovement as m
inner join item..itemrecord as i on m.itemcode = i.itemcode
where m.longdescription <> i.description
```

Check data in longdescription_test randomly. You can actually do a spot check faster by running:

```
select * from movement..itemmovement 
where longdescription <> longdescription_test 
  and longdescription_test is not null
```

If information in longdescription_test looks good, you can change your update statement to set m.longdescription = i.description and run the query again.

It is easier to just create a copy of your itemmovement table before you do the update. To make a copy, you can just do:

```
use movement;
select * into itemmovement_backup from itemmovement;
```

If update does not succeed as desired, you can truncate itemmovement and copy data back from itemmovement_backup.

Answer (score 0):

Zedfoxus provided a GREAT explanation on this and I appreciate it. It is excellent reference for next time around. After reading over some syntax examples, I was confident enough in being able to run the second SQL update query that I have in my OP. Luckily, the data here is not necessarily "live" so at low risk to damage anything, even during operating hours.  Given the nature of the data, the updated executed perfectly, updating all 345,000 entries!